# Send HTML formatted mail with MAPI Mail

Tags: .net, unmanaged, mapi

I am using this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17561/Programmatically-adding-attachments-to-emails-in-C?msg=4112958#xx4112958xx) to send mails using Mapi. But I would like to compose the message in HTML format.

Reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff960439.aspx) and other websites I came across a "constant" called: MAPI_NATIVE_BODY_TYPE_HTML. That gave me the "hope" that things are possible. Unfortunately, I'm not able to make something of it. I'm not used to "convert" unmanged functionality outside the .NET Framework (mapi32.dll) to managed code.

Any ideas / links are welcome.

Comment: There is any specific reason of using MAPI for sending formatted html file?

Comment: Yes. We want to start the default mail client on the end-user's system. So that the end-user can add recipients from it's adrees book and so on. Then it's also stored in the send items folder etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that constant is for use with Extended MAPI, but the first link deals with Simple MAPI (that is what you are using, right?).